# Is this inequality true?

Tags: inequality

Clearly if $a,b >0$ and $p \in \mathbb{N}$
$$
a^{p} + b^{p} \le (a+b)^{p}
$$
Is there a constante $C = C(p)$ such that if  $a,b >0$ and $p \in \mathbb{N}$ then
\begin{equation}
a^{p} - b^{p} \le C(p)(a-b)^{p} ?
\end{equation}

Comment: Does $C(p) = 1$ work?

Comment: $a^{p} - b^{p} \le a^{p} + b^{p} \le (a+b)^{p}$

Comment: Sorry I would like $a^{p} - b^{p} \le C(p)(a-b)^{p} ?$

Comment: @Marcos What lhf said is exactly that with $C(p)=1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to find a constant $C(p)$ such that

$$
a^{p} - b^{p} \le C(p)(a-b)^{p}
$$

for all $a,b > 0$ when $p > 1$.  For example, let $a = n+1$ and $b = n$.  Then

$$
a^p-b^p = (n+1)^p - n^p = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \binom{p}{k} n^k \to \infty
$$

but $a-b = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Suppose that $p>1$. Let $b$ be *huge* and let $a=b+1$.

**Added:** One might argue that choosing $a-b=1$ is unfair. However, since the proposed inequality is *homogeneous*, it really makes no difference. For let $b=kx$ and $b=k(x+1)$, where perhaps $k$ is very large.  Then $a^p-b^p=k^p\left((x+1)^p-x^p\right)$, and $(a-b)^p=k^p$, so our inequality becomes
$$(x+1)^p -x^p \le C(p).$$
If $x$ is large enough, this cannot hold.